# Origin of this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, syntax-error

```
>>> x = True
>>> a={ 1:198 if x else 2:198}
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a={ 1:198 if x else 2:198}
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Even adding braces does not help.

```
>>> a={ (1:198) if x else (2:198) }
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a={ (1:198) if x else (2:198) }
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: If you want to change only the key, `{1 if x else 2: 198}` would work, but this doesn't seem like a particularly idiomatic approach.

Comment: You can't do that, a `dict` literal is defined as `'{', expr, ':', expr '}'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the error is that, as Python is parsing the input, it will go something like this:

```
{
# dictionary or set
{ 1: 
# dictionary where key is 1
{ 1: 198 if x else 2
# dictionary where key is 1 and the value is either 198 or 2, depending on x
{ 1: 198 if x else 2:
# wat?
```

That's why the caret indicates the colon; it's encountering a colon where it either expects either:

- a continuation of the expression defining the value;
- a comma indicating the end of the current key-value pair and the beginning of the next; or
- a closing curly brace indicating the end of the dictionary literal.

As it looks like you're only trying to change the *key* according to `x`, you need to put the ternary expression in the key position:

```
{
# dictionary or set
{ 1 if x else 2: 
# dictionary where key is either 1 or 2, depending on x
{ 1 if x else 2: 198
# dictionary where key is either 1 or 2, depending on x, and the value is 198
{ 1 if x else 2: 198 }
# OK!
```

Comment: Thanks for ur explaination. And No, I simplified the example for asking purpose, both my key,value depends of these conditions, Is there any other way to achieve that? And what about error in the bracketed case.

Comment: @v78 then wouldn't it be easier to do e.g. `a = {1: 198} if x else {2: 'not 198'}`? Could you give a more representative example of the problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: @v78 as to why the brackets don't work, again the colon is not a valid token at that point. The `key: value` syntax only works immediately within `{}`, you can't treat it as an value that you can move around the place (you wouldn't assign a pair `x = 1: 2`, for example)

Answer (score 1):

You still can use dict with just enough braces

```
 dict([(1, 198) if x else (2, 198)])
```

or

```
{1: 198} if x else {2: 198}
```

or, for longer cases

```
 d = {}
 d.update({1: 198} if x else {2: 198})
```

Comment: but, That doesn't answer my question.

Comment: it is explained in  AChampion's comment: curly braces notation require list of expressions separated by semicolon https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Also see Python grammar for yourself https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#primaries curly braces can contain (comma separated key-datum ), yet no key-datum type is supported on its own. I guess language designers did not see need for your construct.